# how to find unstructured date and time from a sentence in python?

Tags: python, date, nlp

when I use this code for extracting the date

dateutil.parser.parse('today is 21 jan 2016')

It throws an error -> ValueError: unknown string format

is there any way to extract dates and time from a sentence???

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extracting date from a string in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3276180/extracting-date-from-a-string-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is! (Python is amazing)

`dateutil.parser.parse("today is 21 jan 2016", fuzzy=True)`

Comment: Thank You sir, but I want to extract multile dates such as here in this string

Comment: import dateutil.parser as dparser

print(dparser.parse("today is 21 jan 2016 and tomarrow is 22 jan 2016", fuzzy=True))

Comment: Dateurl.parser is gonna help you parse a sentence fragment containing a date. Your next problem is to find those fragments from a text, a more complicated problem called (named) entity recognition. You might find answers to that question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10340540/using-the-nltk-to-recognise-dates-as-named-entities and here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19994396/best-way-to-identify-and-extract-dates-from-text-python